# Efficiency while finding data matching in time from two data sets

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, time, dataset

Quantity A in a list, Ta the list of associated times.

Quantity B in a list, Tb the list of associated times.

The size a A and B can be very different, elements in Ta/Tb have been converted to fractional seconds since 1970.

I have a code which works fine to store the indexes for which quantity A is at least within 1 hour of quantity B (and increments the time interval if the number of matches is <50).

But this part is taking the most time to compute in my code, at least 2 minutes (up to 20 for very large datasets) and I wonder if there is any way to make it more time efficient. I have completely no notion of time efficiency in python so apologies if this is naive.

A size if of the order 10<sup>4</sup>

B size is of the order 10<sup>3</sup>

```
a=0
it=1
#I want at least 50 match
while(a<50):
    differences=range(len(Ta))

    #those are the indices of the times in Ta[] which are used for comparison
    A_idx=[-1]*len(Tb)
    A_idx1=[-1]*len(Tb)

    for i in range(0,len(Tb)):
        for j in range(0,len(Ta)):
            differences[j]=fabs(Tb[i]-Ta[j])
        val,idx=min((val,idx) for (idx,val) in enumerate(differences))
        # <it means the closest Ta within it hours.
        if val/3600<it:
            A_idx[i]=idx
            A_idx1[i]=idx
    a=len(A_idx)-A_idx.count(-1)
    if a<50:
        it=it+1

#those are the indices of the times in Tb[] which are used for comparison
B_idx=[i for i in range(len(A_idx)) if A_idx[i]!=-1]

#get rid of the useless values in A_idx1
A_idx1[:]=(value for value in A_idx1 if value!=-1)
```

I have A_idx and A_idx1 which are the same thing because when I was defining B_idx it was changing A_idx too (because the [id(i) for i in A_idx] are all the same I guess).

Is there any line which is poor in a time efficiency perspective? (note that the while loop never actually goes to it=2, it's just a security, I didn't have datasets with less than 50 coincidences within 1 hour yet)
If it is also poor in any other perspective please feel free to let me know !

Oh also, if I run the code twice in a row for the same datasets, the second run can take up to 200 seconds longer than the first one, any reason to it? Is it just dependent on my PC?

Comment: Not really a specific tip, but it sounds like you should give `numpy` a try, it will probably help you speed things up a lot :)

Comment: In fact I already use it, I am extracting my A and B from netCDF files (with netCDF4, which gives you numpy.arrays objects), but since they had different structures and I was lazy (A data has a shape (N,M,1,1) and B data has a shape (L,P) ) so I just transferred everything in the lists A and B. 
So are numpy.array getting looped over faster than lists?

Comment: Looping over a numpy array will probably be slower than looping over a list, but for most operations you don't need to manually loop. Not a 100% sure I understand what your code is doing, but I think you might be able to get the same results by using the `scipy.spatial` functions. Possibly: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

Comment: Sorry if the code/explanation is not clear. I want to compare two same physical quantities (in list A and list B) which have not been measured at the same times (list Ta and list Tb), so I select the indices of measurements in list A that correspond to a measurements in list B that occurred within 1 hour of measurement A.

But the for loops to get the time differences, followed by the if statement which checks that that difference is less than one hour , is taking very long and I was curious to know if that's the most time efficient way of doing it

Comment: Well, assuming you sort by time you can do a binary search so you only need to search that specific subset.